# ASP.NET Core RC2 IIS returning 502 on options request

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We have a ASP.NET Core application that we recently upgraded to RC2. Before the upgrade everything was fine, and after the upgrade everything works in the Dev and Staging environments, but in Production, the app responds with 502 to every request that is not handled by an MVC endpoint:

> **502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.**
>    There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

This means that for instance https://www.myapp.com/somenonexistingroute returns 502 rather than 404, while calls to existing endpoints work fine.

The problem is that we are using the app in a cross origin context, so we need options requests (preflight cors requests) to work, and they also respond with a 502.

All environments are running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.5 and the ASP.NET Core platform handler installed.

What is going on?

**Update**

After some more debugging we discovered that this is probably caused by a bug in the framework. We have created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/782)

Comment: Quick question; you have added `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` and `services.AddCors();` in `ConfigureServices` ?

Comment: Yes, and this works fine in the other environments. Adding these headers through IIS also makes the options requests return 502, causing the browser not to go through with the actual request.

Comment: So, what to the logs say - do you have the subcode 502.{x} ? What differs in the production environment, do you have any load balancing HW/SW? Do you run ARR? Is it deployed on Azure VMs?

Comment: No subcode. It is not deployed in Azure, but on a VM from the same provider that hosts the staging and test environments (allthough they are not identical). I am not sure about load balancing, I think there is a load balancer in front of IIS, but the response clearly comes from IIS so I'm not sure if that's the issue.
The one thing I know is different is that the production environment does not have internet access, so the ASP.NET Core module-installer works a little diferently.

Comment: I am not sure if we have ARR.

Comment: The logs are also not outputting anything related to the requests in question, as far as I can see

Comment: No, the response does not necessarily come from IIS, can you post the full request and response? The error message you are receiving is telling us that there might be something in between the client and the server interrupting the communication (such as a load balancer, reverse proxy etc.).

Comment: Here's the request / response to a non-existing endpoint:https://gist.github.com/severisv/1ae48b792b2bdedbb45c490edd46a7fd

Comment: Options request-response: https://gist.github.com/severisv/541ca55769bc3f0327728dc2cd4ab1a3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113632/discussion-between-marcus-and-fiskeboss).

Comment: im getting the 502 but in an appservice/api app

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late to help, but maybe it helps some other people who face this kind of issue.

I had too a 502 error for preflight requests (option request, angular 5 website -> asp.net core 2.0 web api, iis 7.5).

I found out that **I defined twice the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable** (with the same value); once in the web.config file of my asp.net core web api, and once in the configuration editor of IIS (system.webServer/aspNetCore -> ApplicationHost.config <…> -> enviromentVariables). As soon as I removed one of them (the IIS one, but whichever would work), my preflight requests worked again!

Comment: can you paste your web config values here for reference?

Comment: It was something like that:
<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
But I removed it, and put it, as told above, in the configuration editor of IIS. Thus, when I deploy it to athe IIS of my test env or the one of my prod env it will have, respectively, "Production" or "Test" as a value.

Comment: I meant : Thus, when I deploy it to athe IIS of my test env or the one of my prod env it will have, respectively, "Test" or "Production" as a value.

Comment: sometimes that duplication occurs because the variable is set up higher in the IIS "hieararchy" , with the option LockItem = "true", so your application can't change it and fails